# SQL Quiz that I am working on some sample work

Tags: sql, database, oracle

My database

```
       employee(employee-name, street, city)
       works(employee-name, company-name, salary)
       company(company-name, city)
       manages(employee-name, manager-name)
```

1. Find ’John Doe’s Manager’s Name.
2. Find employee’s whom ’John Doe’ manages.
3. Find all companies that have exactly 75 employees.
4. Find in how many cities is ’First Bank Corp.’ located.
5. Find how many employees work for ’CityBank’ in New York.

I'm stuck on #3, so far i have

```
select company-name 
from company 
inner join works.employee-name, works.company-name
where company-name = '75'
```

I know this is wrong? but am i close? 
I havent even looked @ 4 and 5

Comment: Google for `count()` , `group by` and `having`. If you still cant figure out send me a message. Try it first, that way you learn more. You need a combination of all 3

Comment: so like this select company-name , count(*)                                                              from works                                                                                                          group by company-name                                                                                        having count(*) = 75

Comment: #4 is similar to #3 but include a where for the first bank. #5 should be easy if you do #3 and #4 ... even #5 is easiest that #4

Comment: is my answer correct?

Comment: select company-name, count(*)
from works 
group by company-name
having count(*)=75

Comment: Yes , your solution is correct now, just use `count(employee_name)` to make it more readeable of what are you counting

Comment: so the count(*) means count everything in the works table? so count company name with employee name and salary?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91037/discussion-between-juan-carlos-oropeza-and-linyu21).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT "company - name", count(*)
FROM works
GROUP BY "company - name"
HAVING count(*) = 75
```

Answer (score 0):

ANSWERS: 
 1. select manager-name from manages where employee-name='John Doe'
 2. select employee-name from manages where manager-name='John Doe'
 3. select company-name from works having count(employee-name)=75 group
        by company-name
 4. select count(city) from company where company-name='First Bak Corp'
        group by city
 5. select count(e.employee-name) from employee e join works w on
        e.emp-name=w.emp-name where w.company-name='CityBank' and
        e.city='New York' group by e.emp-name